# Ubuntu One Files Guide for Android?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I can't find any guide or faq anywhere so I have to ask these silly questions.

When I add a new folder to be synced it always claims the folders are empty. How do I set up folders to be synced on the Android?

The photos will not back up as well.  I read another post which suggested that I may need to change where to look from DCIM to dcim.  But there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How do you add a new folder to be synced ;)? There is, just yet, no way to define custom folders to sync. There's no sync at all, actually. At the moment, we only auto-upload your pictures to U1. But sync will come!

This has been fixed in 1.0.4.1 on the Android Market, please let us know if your pictures start getting uploaded. If you wish to upload you're previous pictures, you'll need to close the app (leave with back button or just kill it), and remove the /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.ubuntuone.android.files directory. When you launch U1F, it'll ask if you want to upload all your pics / only future pics / none.